# How can I shorten a test for a list being null or having no elements?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
if (App.selectedPhrases == null || App.selectedPhrases.Count == 0)
```

I know that I can use App.selectedPhrases?.Count to return null if needed but how how can I shorten this test? I can't see a way to check for null or 0 without needing to use the || and have two tests.

Comment: As an aside -- if possible, see if the code can be rewritten such that `App.selectedPhrases` is never `null`, but always a valid collection, if an empty one if there's no data. This can drastically reduce the need for boilerplate code like this, even if you do have shortcuts to rewrite it (`if (!App.selectedPhrases.Any())` reads so much nicer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about setting output value to 0 if the list is null using the `?` you tried:

```
if ((App.selectedPhrases?.Count ?? 0) == 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 (App.selectedPhrases?.Count ?? 0) == 0
```